# angularjs: Set styling of an div Element?

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have an app with a table. Due to the fact that it is really hard to code a table with a scrollable tbody I am using the jquery plugin "[DataTable](http://www.datatables.net/)".

I got it to set the initial settings for the DataTable in angularjs:

```
    angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $scope.table = $('#dances').DataTable({
        paging: false,
        ordering: false,
        scrollY: 50,
        bInfo: false,
        select: true,
        searching: false,
        language: {
            zeroRecords: "",
            emptyTable: "",
            search: "_INPUT_",
            searchPlaceholder: "Search / Suchen ..."
        }
    });
});
```

Now I have my scrollable tbody -> 50pixel.

**What do I want to achieve?**

I would like to edit the height of the tbody depending on the screen size of the browser.

**What have I done?**

I looked into the code in my browser and found the div "dataTables_scrollBody" with my 50 pixels.

[image: Browser Code]

Now after 6 hours it was not possible for me to change the styling of this div element, although I have tried many directions. I have found on the internet the function "angular.element(document.querySelector(.CLASSNAME));"

I tried this, but instead finding the div element I have found the DataTable. Therefore I thought I could try to change the dataTableSettings:

```
  var e = angular.element(document.querySelector('dataTables_scrollBody'));
    e.dataTableSettings[0].oScroll.sY = 40;
    $scope.table.draw();
```

But this didn`t work. The table did a redraw, but with the old value of 50pixels instead of the 40pixels.

Also when I try to find the div elements "dataTable_scroll" or "dances_wrapper" I get every time the DataTable back.

[image: DataTable]

How can I get this div element "dataTables_scrollBody" and append a new styling height?

Thank you